# Inheritance and overridden methods with different params

Tags: inheritance, overriding, typescript

I have an interface that inherits `HTMLElement`:

```
export interface IEElement extends HTMLElement {
    click: (event: IEEvent) => void;
    onmousedown: (event: IEEvent) => void;
    onmousemove: (event: IEEvent) => void;
    onmouseup: (event: IEEvent) => void;
}
```

Getting an error on all the properties:

[image: Error Image]

I guess this is because `click` is type `() => void`, but shouldn't it be overridden by my new schema? How to omit the error (I don't want to rename my properties - if it isn't necessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it optional (use: ?)

```
export interface IEElement extends HTMLElement {
    click: (event?: IEEvent) => void;
    onmousedown: (event: IEEvent) => void;
    onmousemove: (event: IEEvent) => void;
    onmouseup: (event: IEEvent) => void;
}
```

Comment: It worked but now I got an error. When I try to use my interface and simply assign a new value to it, I get a message: "Cannot set property 'onmousedown' of undefined" o_O

Comment: @Nickon I think you should open a new question for that, it is not related to this issues (as far as I see it..)